# Why logical OR working differently if change the order contains terinary operator

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

Why below code is giving different outputs?

```js
var test;

var output = test ? 'Test' : 'No Test' || true;
var output2 = true || test ? 'Test' : 'No Test'

console.log(output); // No Test
console.log(output2); // Test
```

Comment: Why *would* it work the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). The conditional operator has precedence 4, while logical OR has precedence 5, so your code is equivalent to:

```js
var test;

var output = test ? 'Test' : ('No Test' || true);
//      undefined ? 'Test' : 'No Test'
var output2 = (true || test) ? 'Test' : 'No Test'
//                      true ? 'Test' : 'No Test'

console.log(output);
console.log(output2);
```

The OR grouping has a higher priority - its surrounding tokens are grouped together first.

Answer (score 0):

```
var output2 = true || test ? 'Test' : 'No Test'
```

> in this above code you used `true` thats why it has printed `Test` your conditional operator here got as true

```
var output2 = test ? 'Test' : 'No Test'
```

if you have tried like this it will print `No Test`

```js
var test;

var output = test ? 'Test' : 'No Test' || true;
var output2 = test ? 'Test' : 'No Test'

console.log(output); // No Test
console.log(output2); // Test
```